# Aframe Sphere-Collider trigger function on collision

Tags: html, aframe

I have two entities in Aframe on different AR Markers and would like to trigger a certain function on their collision. 
I've added [Aframe-Extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras) to make use of the Sphere-Collider Module. Unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation for it.

How would I link to objects and call a global function on their collision? I guess I need to bind it somehow via js?

My current html looks like this:

```
<a-scene embedded arjs='trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false; patternRatio: 0.7;'>
    <a-marker preset='custom' type='pattern' url='patterns/1.patt'>
        <a-box sphere-collider color="navy" depth="1" height="1" width="1" position="1 0 0"></a-box>
    </a-marker>

    <a-marker preset='custom' type='pattern' url='patterns/2.patt'>
        <a-sphere sphere-collider color="blue" position="1 0 0" radius="0.5"></a-sphere>
    </a-marker>


    <!-- add a simple camera -->
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

[image]

Thanks a lot!

## Update 1

Can it also work on Ar.js Markers?

```
<a-marker preset='custom' type='pattern' url='patterns/1.patt'>
    <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" foo></a-box>
    <a-sphere sphere-collider='' position="3 0.5 -3" radius="0.25" color="#EF2D5E">
        <a-animation attribute="position" dur="5000" fill="forwards" to="-1 0.5 -3" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
    </a-sphere>
</a-marker>
```

Find a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jk4gbu13/5/

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sphere-collider` should emit a `hit` event with intersection details.

Having an entity with the collider:

```
<a-box sphere-collider></a-box>
<a-sphere></sphere>
```

You can listen on the sphere for the `hit` and `hitend` events to detect when the collision occured, and when it ended

```
this.el.addEventListener('hit', (e) => {
   console.log(e)
})
this.el.addEventListener('hitend', (e) => {
    console.log('hitend')
    console.log(e)
})
```

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s12gjfc4/).

---

Ngo Kevin's [aabb-collider](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/aabb-collider/) seems to work fine with `ar.js` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dfj1tba/)). Although it has a `hitstart` instead of `hit` event.

Comment: Last question: why does the script need to run before the index is read? When I register the component at the end of the index, it doesn't work.

Comment: Found the answer here: https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html

Comment: @vinni glad i could help anyway :)

Comment: the last thing I'm trying to figure right now is, why it doesn't work within ar.js.

I'm not sure the component is registered correctly if it's inside a marker tag?

Comment: @vinni i'll check it out when i get home. If you throw a `console.log("foo")` into the `init` function you'll be sure if the component is properly registered.

Comment: I'll prepare you a fiddle

Comment: Added an update with the fiddle into the question :)

Comment: I think the component is registered alright. It seems to only be working when the elements are direct children of `<a-scene>` inside it doesnt work.

Comment: Seems ngoKevin's [aabb-collider](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/aabb-collider/) works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/2dfj1tba/ . If the sphere collider is not working with nested elements, then it's a buggy bug

Comment: Nice! I'll test that!

Comment: Yes, all works fine. Thank you so much! Really appreciate the quick help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185129/discussion-between-vinni-and-piotr-adam-milewski).