# Collision with A-Frame objects using JavaScript physics library

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

So, I have been stumped on this for a while now. I need to be able to have my camera entity collide with shape entities within an A-frame scene stopping the camera from going through them. Essentially I want to create walls using the A-Frame physics engine that can be found here:

https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system

I have searched all over and am unable to find a simple example of how to obtain this function! I have already spent far too much time looking around online.

I have created a simple scene in A-Frame with the basics of Don's physics engine already included. I created this in order to try to test out a single walls function before adding it to my far more complex scene I am working on.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.3/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/v4.0.1/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>
    <title>Aframe Physics Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene physics="debug: true">

        <a-entity id="camera" position="0 1.6 0">
            <!-- Camera Entity -->
            <a-entity id="camera" acceleration="200w" camera look-controls wasd-controls></a-entity>
        </a-entity>

        <a-box static-body position="0 0 -3" color="#4CC3D9" width="8" height="5" depth="0.5"></a-box>

        <a-plane static-body rotation="-90 0 0" position="0 0 -4" width="10" height="10" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
        <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the physics engine to detect collisions with the camera - it needs to be a part of the physics engine. It can't be a `static-body` because it needs to move around, and it can't be a `dynamic-body` for it needs to be controlled by the player, and not fall down (gravity) and spin around.

Don McCurdy created a `kinematic-body` component having the camera / player in mind. It is available as part of the [physics extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/dist/aframe-extras.js)

---

So having a camera:

```
<a-entity camera kinematic-body></a-entity>
```

You can detect any objects it collides with:

```
// inside an a-frame component - this is straight from the docs
this.el.addEventListener('collide', function(e) {
   console.log('Player has collided with ', e.detail.body.el);
   e.detail.target.el; // Original entity (camera).
   e.detail.body.el; // Other entity, which the camera touched.
   e.detail.contact; // Stats about the collision (CANNON.ContactEquation).
   e.detail.contact.ni; // Normal (direction) of the collision (CANNON.Vec3).
});
```

Check it out below:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/deprecated/Geometry.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.js"></script>
<script src="https://n5ro.github.io/aframe-physics-system/dist/aframe-physics-system.js"></script>

<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
    init: function() {
      this.el.addEventListener('collide', function(e) {
        console.log('Player has collided with ', e.detail.body.el);
      });
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene physics="debug: true">
  <a-entity id="rig" movement-controls kinematic-body foo>
    <a-entity id="camera" camera position="0 1.6 0" look-controls></a-entity>
  </a-entity>
  <a-box static-body position="0 0 -3" color="#4CC3D9" width="8" height="5" depth="0.5"></a-box>
  <a-sphere dynamic-body position="0 1 -2" color="#4CC3D9"></a-sphere>
  <a-box scale="20 0.01 20" static-body></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

---

If the shapes are simple consider using a [box collider](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/aabb-collider/) or a sphere collider. There is a simple example in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53674123/2425787).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. It seems that whenever I add a new static-body to my more complex scene, I am getting "ghost collisions" and running into invisible objects. these invisible objects change location as I change the camera start location. Any idea what may be happening happening?

Comment: are the bodies complex models ? does collision meshes show up on debug mode, or are you bouncing off 'nothing' ?

Comment: It seemed to be a problem with nesting the camera entity within a position entity. Collision works properly when I remove the outer entity the camera is nested within, however the y-axis position will not stay at 1.6 and falls to the static plane position once the camera entity is no longer nested. Weird issues I am having.

Comment: Is having a rig with `movement-controls`, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60558635/2425787) better ?

Comment: Unfortunately the fiddle sample is not working with the current version (1.3.0) of A-FRAME. Do you know what needs to be changed to make a simple camera collision detection (e.g. collide with with a box), with the current A-FRAME version? I tried to use Ammo Driver (aframe-physics-system) but still could not make camera stop when colliding with a wall.
My goal is to stop moving when camera hits a wall, instead of going through it. Here is what I tried to do but unfortunately camera goes through the wall when navigating using arrow keys: https://js.do/rsiqueira/vr-physics-collision
Thanks.

Comment: I'll try looking into it. Did you tried using navigation meshes like the suggestion in your link?

Comment: @RodrigoDeAlmeidaSiqueira I've added a snippet.